# Couchbase: Why any Time Zone is automatically converting to Local Time Zone when retrieving from Couchbase SDK

Tags: c#, sdk, timezone, couchbase

I facing an issue when retrieving date and time along with time zone in C# using couchbase SDK. Please find the details below.

### This is the couchbase Insert Query which is having different country date and time along with time zone

#### Upsert Query

```
UPSERT INTO DtTest (KEY,VALUE) 
VALUES ( "TZ:Dates", {
    "Tokyo" : "2020-06-18T15:26:00+09:00",
    "Beijing" : "2020-06-18T14:26:00+08:00",
    "Moscow" : "2020-06-18T09:26:00+03:00",
    "Paris" : "2020-06-18T08:26:00+02:00",
    "LosAngeles" : "2020-06-17T23:26:00-07:00"
})
```

### This is couchbase Select Query, where we can check by using console

#### Select Query

```
`select * from DtTest use keys "TZ:Dates"`
```

#### Couchbase Select Query Result in console and we didnt see any issue here

```
{
  "Beijing": "2020-06-18T14:26:00+08:00",
  "LosAngeles": "2020-06-17T23:26:00-07:00",
  "Moscow": "2020-06-18T09:26:00+03:00",
  "Paris": "2020-06-18T08:26:00+02:00",
  "Tokyo": "2020-06-18T15:26:00+09:00"
}
```

### When we are trying to retrieving from Couchbase SDK in C#

#### Couchbase SDK code in C#

```
`_bucket.Get<dynamic>("TZ:Dates");`
```

#### Couchbase SDK Result in C# which is converting the timezone to my system local timezone

```
{
  "Beijing": "2020-06-18T11:56:00+05:30",
  "LosAngeles": "2020-06-18T11:56:00+05:30",
  "Moscow": "2020-06-18T11:56:00+05:30",
  "Paris": "2020-06-18T11:56:00+05:30",
  "Tokyo": "2020-06-18T11:56:00+05:30"
}
```

**Note** : *Please help me on this to retrieve exact time zones how we are getting from Couchbase Console*

Comment: Please help me on this as can we have any property to get it same result as we get from console result from couchbase SDK in C#

Comment: This was also posted in the Couchbase forums, and there is some more discussion there - https://forums.couchbase.com/t/why-any-time-zone-is-automatically-converting-to-local-time-zone-when-retrieving-from-couchbase-sdk/26461

Comment: I only did this. thanks for response